# in ng2-charts multiple pie charts not showing

Tags: angular, pie-chart, ng2-charts

This is my html code what i am doing is call the API and bind the data to the charts and it is for multiple charts...

`<ng-container *ngFor="let historyitem of historydata?.data; let i=index;">
    <div class="post history_post wow fadeInUp" id="{{historyitem.id}}" *ngIf="historyitem.party?.length > 0">
    <canvas baseChart width="400" height="200" [data]="chartdata" [labels]="chartlabel" [colors]="ChartColors" [legend]="true" [chartType]="ChartType"></canvas>
</div>
</ng-container>`

and this is how i am getting an api resopnse and my doubt is how to bind the party -> seats to datasets or data and bind the party -> partyname to the label ?? I am still confused how to do this any help ??, i am able to get single chart if i call map method but map method didn't work for multiple array objects how to resolve this issue ??

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            "year": 2018,
            "government": "INC,JDS",
            "election_type": "GENERAL_ELECTION",
            "state_government_url": "karnataka-inc-jds-2018",
            "start_date": "2018-05-23",
            "end_date": "2023-05-23",
            "description": "The 15th Karnataka Legislative Assembly was constituted after the Karnataka Legislative Assembly elections in 2018. Polling was held on 12 May[1] for 222 constituencies out of the 224-member assembly,[2] with counting of votes and results declared on 15 May.[3] The term of the assembly is for five years.",
            "likes_count": 0,
            "comments_count": 0,
            "share_count": 0,
            "favourites_count": 0,
            "liked": false,
            "emoji": "NA",
            "added_to_favourite": false,
            "party": []
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "year": 2018,
            "government": "BJP",
            "election_type": "GENERAL_ELECTION",
            "state_government_url": "karnataka-bjp-2018",
            "start_date": "2018-05-17",
            "end_date": "2018-05-19",
            "description": "The 15th Karnataka Legislative Assembly was constituted after the Karnataka Legislative Assembly elections in 2018. Polling was held on 12 May[1] for 222 constituencies out of the 224-member assembly,[2] with counting of votes and results declared on 15 May.[3] The term of the assembly is for five years.",
            "likes_count": 0,
            "comments_count": 0,
            "share_count": 0,
            "favourites_count": 1,
            "liked": false,
            "emoji": "NA",
            "added_to_favourite": true,
            "party": []
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "year": 2013,
            "government": "INC",
            "election_type": "GENERAL_ELECTION",
            "state_government_url": "karnataka-inc-2013",
            "start_date": "2013-05-13",
            "end_date": "2018-05-17",
            "description": "INC",
            "likes_count": 3,
            "comments_count": 0,
            "share_count": 0,
            "favourites_count": 1,
            "liked": true,
            "emoji": "0x1F62F",
            "added_to_favourite": false,
            "party": [
                {
                    "party": {
                        "party_name": "INC",
                        "party_abbervation": "Indian National Congress"
                    },
                    "seats": 122
                },
                {
                    "party": {
                        "party_name": "BJP",
                        "party_abbervation": "Bharatiya Janata Party"
                    },
                    "seats": 40
                },
                {
                    "party": {
                        "party_name": "JD(S)",
                        "party_abbervation": "Janata Dal (Secular)"
                    },
                    "seats": 40
                },
                {
                    "party": {
                        "party_name": "IND",
                        "party_abbervation": "Independent"
                    },
                    "seats": 9
                },
                {
                    "party": {
                        "party_name": "KJP",
                        "party_abbervation": "Karnataka Janatha Paksha"
                    },
                    "seats": 6
                },
                {
                    "party": {
                        "party_name": "BSRCP ",
                        "party_abbervation": "Badavara Shramikara Raitara Congress Party"
                    },
                    "seats": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "year": 2008,
            "government": "BJP",
            "election_type": "GENERAL_ELECTION",
            "state_government_url": "karnataka-bjp-2008",
            "start_date": "2008-05-30",
            "end_date": "2013-05-05",
            "description": "BJP",
            "likes_count": 2,
            "comments_count": 0,
            "share_count": 0,
            "favourites_count": 1,
            "liked": false,
            "emoji": "NA",
            "added_to_favourite": true,
            "party": [
                {
                    "party": {
                        "party_name": "BJP",
                        "party_abbervation": "Bharatiya Janata Party"
                    },
                    "seats": 117
                },
                {
                    "party": {
                        "party_name": "INC",
                        "party_abbervation": "Indian National Congress"
                    },
                    "seats": 82
                },
                {
                    "party": {
                        "party_name": "JD(S)",
                        "party_abbervation": "Janata Dal (Secular)"
                    },
                    "seats": 31
                },
                {
                    "party": {
                        "party_name": "IND",
                        "party_abbervation": "Independent"
                    },
                    "seats": 7
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "code": 201,
    "message": "State government information retrieved successfully."
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You mention "html code", but i'm only seeing a json snippet? Please read how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

For a Pie chart, you need to bind it to a set of arrays (one with labels and the 2nd array with data).

Since your data contains multiple elections data, you can ask the user for the election which they are interested in... and then traverse your data to fill the set of arrays (labels and data).

If you want more than one chart, you'd have more than one set of arrays (labels and data).

You can check a [working demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jgxsp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Upgrade your `ng2-charts` dependency to 2.0.3 - it fixes the colors issue